# How to understand this code of flask?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

Could anyone explain this line？

```
g = LocalProxy(lambda: _request_ctx_stack.top.g)
```

code from flask

```
from werkzeug import LocalStack, LocalProxy

# context locals
_request_ctx_stack = LocalStack()
current_app = LocalProxy(lambda: _request_ctx_stack.top.app)
request = LocalProxy(lambda: _request_ctx_stack.top.request)
session = LocalProxy(lambda: _request_ctx_stack.top.session)
g = LocalProxy(lambda: _request_ctx_stack.top.g)
```

code of Local is here:  http://pastebin.com/U3e1bEi0

Comment: Lambda is being used because LocalProxy() takes a function argument.

Answer (score 6):

The [Werkzeug documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/local/) for LocalStack and LocalProxy might help, as well as some basic understanding of [WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface).

It appears what is going on is that a global (but empty) stack `_request_ctx_stack` is created.  This is available to all threads.  Some WSGI-style objects (`current_app`, `request`, `session`, and `g`) are set to use the top item in the global stack.

At some point, one or more WSGI applications are pushed onto the global stack.  Then, when, for example, `current_app` is used at runtime, the current top application is used.  If the stack is never initialized, then top will return None and you'll get an exception like `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'`.

Comment: Nearly correct but not completely. The _request_ctx_stack is a stack of request contexts, which hold the current app, the request, the session and the request globals. These contexts are pushed on the stack on a per request basis, otherwise this could not work.